# Sort variable contents in numeric order

Tags: php, sorting

I have the variable:

```
$data = "Article 4 Article 2 Article 10";
```

I need to have this output:

```
Article 2 Article 4 Article 10
```

I tried something like this:

```
<?php

$data = "Article 4 Article 2 Article 10";

function sort_titles_article_numbers($a,$b) {
    $akey = $a->$data;
    if (preg_match('/^Article (\d+)\. /', $akey, $matches)) {
        $akey = $matches[1];
    }
    $bkey = $b->$data;
    if (preg_match('/^Article (\d+)\. /', $bkey, $matches)) {
        $bkey = $matches[1];
    }
    if ($akey == $bkey) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($akey < $bkey) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($data,'sort_titles_article_numbers');

echo $data;

?>
```

But something wrong. It seems that uasort works only for arrays, but how i could sort it inside of variable?

Comment: Why aren't you using an array to store the values? Using one string to store several string values is kind of asking for trouble.

Comment: Turn the string into an array, sort it, and then spit it back out as a string.

Comment: @Chris yes you are right that storing in array is a better way, but i have a big piece of text data. and for me is interesting is there any other ways.

Comment: @user2337706 `uasort` is working with arrays, you are giving it a single string, what the purpose of it in that case?

Comment: @Cheery i found function "sort_titles_article_numbers" on the net. i like that they use preg_match('/^Article (\d+). And i was suposing there is a way to use preg to sort single array. I am beginner and i try everything.

Comment: @user2337706 you still have to break the string into array to sort. Even when you are trying to use `uasort` and your function.

Comment: @Cherry Thanks, now i understand that there is no other way, only through arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = "Article 4 Article 2 Article 10";

// line below splits string by number, keeping it, and trims elements of array
$tmp = array_map('trim', preg_split('/\d+\K/', $data));

natsort($tmp); // very useful function for 'natural' sorting

echo join(' ', $tmp);  // converts array to string
```

Result - `Article 2 Article 4 Article 10`

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to sort array numerically if you want give priority only to numbers:

```
$data = "Artihcle 4 Artizcle 2 Article 10";

$tmp = preg_split('/\w \d+\K/', $data);


usort($tmp, function ($a, $b) {
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $a, $matchA);
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $b, $matchB);
    return $matchA[0] - $matchB[0];
});


$data2 = join(' ', $tmp);

echo trim($data2);
```